# join foreign keys' cardinality (relational algebra)

Tags: join, relational-algebra

What's the cardinality (the number of rows) for multiple joins with foreign keys, from different tables? And why?

For example

```
(R1⋈(b=d)R2) ⋈(f=g)R3
```

The relations are:

- R1 (a,b,c) -- a is primary key
- R2 (d,e,f) -- d and e are primary keys
- R3 (g,h,i) -- g is primary key

where b references d, and f references g.
Are the number of rows exactly R1 or they're between R1 and R1*R3? Hope you guys understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

There being a foreign key R A referencing S B means (a) every value for S A appears in S B and b) B is a key of S. If you join R with S on A=B then by per (a) every R row has a match in S and per (b) it has only one match in S. So the join has the same number of rows as S.

If there is a foreign key from a column in a table then the result of a join on that column has the same foreign key. This is because the result only has values of that column that that table did, so every value of that column in the result is also in the referenced table and column.

So for your example: The first join has S1 rows. The result has a foreign key from f to R3 g because S2 did. So the result of the second join has S1 rows.